# Beamer foot-line alignment: bug?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, vertical-alignment

Happy New Year to you!

I am trying to create a Beamer document, and I realised that the foot-line's alignment is off. Is there any way to fix this? Since some TexLive update, I realised all my new typeset documents are misaligned - it used to be normal in the past.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title[Title]{This is the title}

\author[Name]{Author's name}
\institute[Institute]{Author's Institute}
\date[Date]{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems indeed a bug: compiling with TeX Live 2016 produces the expected result.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! Is there any way to mitigate this issue? Cheers

Comment: I guess this is https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/446

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like a bug, because I also obtain the expected result. As a workaround, maybe you can play with the `\boxheight` parameter in the following code? The default is `2.25ex`, and it determines the distance between the baseline of the text and the top border of the footer boxes. Try with `2.75ex` and see if the problem is solved.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\newcommand{\boxheight}{2.25ex}
\newcommand{\boxdepth}{1ex}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=\boxheight,dp=\boxdepth,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=\boxheight,dp=\boxdepth,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=\boxheight,dp=\boxdepth,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\title[Title]{This is the title}

\author[Name]{Author's name}
\institute[Institute]{Author's Institute}
\date[Date]{\today}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @javi_gg1. Cheers for the help, and I appreciate it. Happy 2018 to you and the community!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't - the text is aligned to the the top of the box, and it shifts with the size of the box.